# Prove that there exists a c such that $f(c)^2 = c$, when $f(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Show that if $-1 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ belonging to $[0,1]$, then there is $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(c)^2 = c$.

I was thinking, this could be proved using Sandwich theorem. This is how far I got.

$-1 \leq f(c) \leq 1$

$(-1)^2 \leq f(c)^2 \leq (1)^2$

$1 \leq f(c)^2 \leq 1$

Since limit of both sides is $1$, limit of $f(c)^2$ as $c$ approaches $0$ would also be $1$.

I am not sure if this proves that $f(c)^2 = c$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer: sorry about overwriting your edit; MSE warned me that an edit had been made, but I hoped I'd actually get to see that edit when I pressed save. That didn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** 
Consider the function $g(x) = f(x)^2 - x$. Then 
$g(0) \ge 0$ and $g(1) \le 0$.

EDIT: Also, there is a large flaw in your attempted argument, when $a$ is negative, $a \le x$ doesn't mean $a^2 \le x^2$. For instance

$$-\sqrt{2^{{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}}}}} < 0$$

but 
$$2^{{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}}}} > 0$$